# Basic snake game in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I wanted to learn C and Win32 so I thought the best way to start would be to create a simple game to get familiar with the language, so I made Snake. The games works perfectly except for sometimes seeing the game window flash for a split second, don't know what causes it.

Code:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define TIMER_MAIN 42069

HWND gameWindow;
HFONT gameFont;

int timeElapsed = 0;
int direction = 0;
int length = 0;
int width, height, bSize, snakeThinness;

POINT* playerHistory;
POINT playerLocation = { 0 };
POINT fruitLocation = { 0 };

void Die(int errorCode)
{
    if (gameFont)
        DeleteObject(gameFont);
    char error[6][64] = {   "Finished program execution", 
                            "Could not register window class", 
                            "Could not create window",
                            "Win32 Error",
                            "Player direction is outside 2D space",
                            "" };
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
    printf("Halting: (0x%08x) %s\r\nWIN 0x%08x / %s", errorCode, error[errorCode], dw, (LPCSTR)lpMsgBuf);
    exit(errorCode);
}

void GameInit(int w, int h, int bS)
{
    printf("%s\n", "Initiating game variables...");
    width = w;
    height = h;
    bSize = bS;
    snakeThinness = bSize / 10;
    timeElapsed = 0;
    direction = 0;
    length = 0;
    playerLocation.x = 4;
    playerLocation.y = 4;
    while (1)
    {
        fruitLocation.x = rand() % width;
        fruitLocation.y = rand() % height;
        if (fruitLocation.x == playerLocation.x && fruitLocation.y == playerLocation.y)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
    RECT rc, rcClient;
    GetWindowRect(gameWindow, &rc);
    GetClientRect(gameWindow, &rcClient);
    int xExtra = rc.right - rc.left - rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
    int yExtra = rc.bottom - rc.top - rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;
    SetWindowPos(gameWindow, NULL, NULL, NULL, (width * bSize) + xExtra, (height * bSize) + yExtra, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOCOPYBITS);
}

void GameLoop()
{
    int lastX = playerLocation.x;
    int lastY = playerLocation.y;
    switch (direction)
    {   
        //0 == right
        //1 == bottom
        //2 == left
        //3 == top
        case 0:
            playerLocation.x++;
            if (playerLocation.x > width)
                playerLocation.x = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            playerLocation.y++;
            if (playerLocation.y > height)
                playerLocation.y = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            playerLocation.x--;
            if (playerLocation.x < 0)
                playerLocation.x = width;
            break;
        case 3:
            playerLocation.y--;
            if (playerLocation.y < 0)
                playerLocation.y = height;
            break;
        default:
            Die(4);
    }
    POINT p;
    p.x = lastX;
    p.y = lastY;
    if (fruitLocation.x == playerLocation.x && fruitLocation.y == playerLocation.y)
    {
        length++;
        if (playerHistory != 0)
        {
            POINT* playerHistory2 = (POINT*) malloc(length * sizeof(POINT));
            //memcpy(playerHistory2 + sizeof(POINT), playerHistory, (length - 1)  * sizeof(POINT));
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
                playerHistory2[i + 1] = playerHistory[i];
            playerHistory2[0] = p;
            free(playerHistory);
            playerHistory = playerHistory2;
        }
        else
        {
            playerHistory = (POINT*) malloc(length * sizeof(POINT));
        }
        if (length == 1)
        {
            playerHistory[0] = p;
        }
        while (1)
        {
            fruitLocation.x = rand() % width;
            fruitLocation.y = rand() % height;
            if (fruitLocation.x == playerLocation.x && fruitLocation.y == playerLocation.y)
                continue;
            int t = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                if (fruitLocation.x == playerHistory[i].x && fruitLocation.y == playerHistory[i].y)
                    t = 1;
            if (t == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (playerHistory != 0)
    {
        POINT* playerHistory2 = (POINT*) malloc(length * sizeof(POINT));
        //memcpy(playerHistory2 + sizeof(POINT), playerHistory, (length - 1) * sizeof(POINT));
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            playerHistory2[i + 1] = playerHistory[i];
        playerHistory2[0] = p;
        free(playerHistory);
        playerHistory = playerHistory2;
    }
    int willDie = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (playerLocation.x == playerHistory[i].x && playerLocation.y == playerHistory[i].y)
            willDie = 1;
    if (willDie == 1)
        GameInit(width, height, bSize);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    switch (uMsg) 
    { 
        case WM_CREATE:
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Window succesfully created", "Succes", MB_OK);
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
            SetTimer(hwnd, TIMER_MAIN, 375, (TIMERPROC) NULL);
            return 0; 
        case WM_TIMER:
            switch (wParam) 
            { 
                case TIMER_MAIN: 
                    timeElapsed++;
                    GameLoop();
                    RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
                    return 0;
            } 
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT: 
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            RECT rect;
            //Clear screen
            rect.left = 0;
            rect.right = width * bSize;
            rect.top = 0;
            rect.bottom = height * bSize;
            FillRect(hdc, &rect, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
            //Draw fruit
            rect.left = fruitLocation.x * bSize;
            rect.right = (fruitLocation.x + 1) * bSize;
            rect.top = fruitLocation.y * bSize;
            rect.bottom = (fruitLocation.y + 1) * bSize;
            FillRect(hdc, &rect, GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
            //Draw player tail
            int lastX = playerLocation.x;
            int lastY = playerLocation.y;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                int doNormal = 0;
                int compare1, compare2;
                if (lastY == playerHistory[i].y)
                {
                    compare1 = playerHistory[i].x;
                    compare2 = lastX;
                }
                else
                {
                    compare1 = playerHistory[i].y;
                    compare2 = lastY;
                }
                if (abs(compare1 - compare2) == 1)
                {
                    if (compare1 < compare2)
                    {
                        rect.left = (playerHistory[i].x * bSize) + snakeThinness;
                        rect.right = ((lastX + 1) * bSize) - snakeThinness;
                        rect.top = (playerHistory[i].y * bSize) + snakeThinness;
                        rect.bottom = ((lastY + 1) * bSize) - snakeThinness;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rect.left = (lastX * bSize) + snakeThinness;
                        rect.right = ((playerHistory[i].x + 1) * bSize) - snakeThinness;
                        rect.top = (lastY * bSize) + snakeThinness;
                        rect.bottom = ((playerHistory[i].y + 1) * bSize) - snakeThinness;
                    }
                }
                else
                    doNormal = 1;
                if (doNormal)
                {
                    rect.left = (playerHistory[i].x * bSize) + snakeThinness;
                    rect.right = ((playerHistory[i].x + 1) * bSize) - snakeThinness;
                    rect.top = (playerHistory[i].y * bSize) + snakeThinness;
                    rect.bottom = ((playerHistory[i].y + 1) * bSize) - snakeThinness;
                }
                lastX = playerHistory[i].x;
                lastY = playerHistory[i].y;
                FillRect(hdc, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0)));
            }
            //Draw player
            rect.left = playerLocation.x * bSize;
            rect.right = (playerLocation.x + 1) * bSize;
            rect.top = playerLocation.y * bSize;
            rect.bottom = (playerLocation.y + 1) * bSize;
            FillRect(hdc, &rect, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
            rect.left = 0;
            rect.right = width * bSize;
            rect.top = 0;
            rect.bottom = 30;
            SelectObject(hdc, gameFont);
            SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(128, 128, 128));
            SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
            int strLen = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%i", length);
            char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strLen + 1 + 7));
            sprintf(str, "Score: %i", length);
            DrawText(hdc, str, -1, &rect, DT_CENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0; 
        case WM_SIZE: 
            return 0; 
        case WM_DESTROY: 
            Die(0);
            return 0;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if ((lParam & 0x40000000) == 0)
            {
                switch (wParam)
                {
                    case VK_RIGHT:
                        if (direction != 2)
                            direction = 0;
                        return;
                    case VK_DOWN:
                        if (direction != 3)
                            direction = 1;
                        return;
                    case VK_LEFT:
                        if (direction != 0)
                            direction = 2;
                        return;
                    case VK_UP:
                        if (direction != 1)
                            direction = 3;
                        return;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        default: 
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", "Starting...");
    HINSTANCE module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { 0 };
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndClass.style = NULL;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) MainWndProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wndClass.hInstance = module;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName =  ""; 
    wndClass.lpszClassName = "MainWindowClass"; 

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wndClass))
        Die(1);

    gameWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "MainWindowClass", "CSnake", WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 460, 460, NULL, NULL, module, NULL);
    if (gameWindow == NULL)
        Die(2);

    gameFont = CreateFont(28, 0, 0, 0, 400, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_PITCH, "Comic Sans MS");

    GameInit(20, 20, 20);

    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;

    while (1)
    {
        bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);

        if (bRet > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else if (bRet < 0)
        {
            Die(3);
        }
        else
        {
            Die(0);
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```
````